# How can I insert links into HTML using javascript without the limitations of document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

First, let me explain what I am trying to accomplish. I currently have 8 small websites that are identical except for a header image and the href links.

I am looking for a way to minimize maintenance and potential for human error each time these pages need updating.

For example, say I have 2 links that point to State specific login pages.

```
<a href="https://www.mypage.com/studentLogin?stateId=WA">Student Login</a>
<a href="https://www.mypage.com/teacherLogin?stateId=WA">Teacher Login</a>
```

In the past, I have been making copies of the updated HTML, then search and replace "stateId=WA" for "stateId=MI"

I started to see if I could make the URL using javascript and just append the 2 digit State ID using some function. That way I would only have to update the code, then copy it and replace the 2 digit state ID in one place, in one file.

I made progress by using the following external javascript file

```
function getParam() {
return 'WA';
}

function getLink() {
document.getElementById('studentLogin').href = 'https://www.mypage.com/studentLogin?stateId=' + getParam();
}

function getLink() {
document.getElementById('teacherLogin').href = 'https://www.mypage.com/teacherLogin?stateId=' + getParam();
```

and then using this in the HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="getLink();" id="studentLogin">CLICK ME</a>
```

This worked, until I figured out that I can't have more than one element in the HTML with the same id. For example, one of the pages has a link to the Student Login in the Menu, and also has a link to the same place in the main content of the HTML, and only one of them would work.

So I suppose I could create several functions in the external javascript file each with their own ID, then update the HTML to call the new IDs, but I am in search of a better way.

All I really care about is minimizing maintenance, since I currently have 8 of these landing pages, but we could have more in the near future. Since there are only 4 distinct links off of these pages, it would be fine if I could figure out how to store the entire link in a variable, and just call that variable in the

```
<a> tag
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can add classes to the relevant links, and then get the elements with `document.getElementsByClassName("myclass")`

```
<a href="#" class="myclass">test1</a><a href="#" class="myclass">test2</a>
```

And in JS:

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass")
```

This would make links an array containing all the links over which you could iterate to apply your modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for a progressive enhancement.

I would suggest you add a attribute the html link; data-state-change.  Then any future links you write you just add the attribute.

```
//keep the base url in the tag
<a href="https://www.mypage.com/studentLogin" data-has-state>Click Me<a>

//now using jquery attach to all links that have that data- element.
$('body').on('click', '[data-has-state]', function(e){
   // eat the click
   e.preventDefault();

   //get the url
   var url = $(this).attr('href') + '?stateId=' + getParam();

   window.location = url;
);
```

You could do something similar with a css class also instead of an html data- attribute.  Then it would be.

```
 $('body').on('click', '.someCssClass', function(e){
       // eat the click
       e.preventDefault();

       //get the url
       var url = $(this).attr('href') + '?stateId=' + getParam();

       window.location = url;
    );
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, I like this idea, because then the only thing I need to change is a single entry in the `getParam()` function. However, I am in need of some additional help because I am not getting it to work. My site is already using jQuery, the template I found was using version 1.7.1. I am not sure if I have to somehow add this functionality to the base jQuery file. Since I didn't know how to do that, I just put the code you gave me at the end of the HTML page, before, the closing </body> tag. Do I just put the text `data-has-state` in the <a> tag, without any sort of parameter?

Comment: If you're just embedding it in the page you'll need to wrap the call in this so that it loads after the page is done.  You don't need to put any value in the data-has-state.  It's common to do so with data attributes but it's not required. $(function() { //put code here }

Comment: I still can not get this function to work. Based on your feedback, I have created a jsfiddle page, with a simple link, and the JS you gave me.

[JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/thecheeto/LBs4h/1/)

The link should take the invalid url used in the href tag `http://www.goo` and append `gle.com` to the end of it, making it a valid link to `www.google.com` but it does not work. Can you see what I am missing?

Comment: my bad, I didn't put e in the function.  I fixed it above.

Comment: That works exactly like what I wanted. Thank you so much.

I am having one more issue, but it might require a new post. It appears a jQuery add-on is interfering with the code you gave me. The links works like I want in the main part of the page, but in the Menu, which is a collection of unordered lists organized into a menu by something called `Dropotron` [Link to Github Project Page](https://github.com/n33/jquery.dropotron)

The code appears to not run at all, and the `?stateId=MI` does not get applied. I figure that Dropoton is somehow preventing the behavior I am looking for in the menus

Comment: My guess would be your navigation isn't inside the body tag.  The above code is capturing the clicks for stuff inside the body tag.